# pop() middle two elements from list

Tags: python, list, methods

Just doing a review of my Python class and noticed that I forgot how to do this.

```
def outsideIn2(lst):

'''(list)->list

Returns a new list where the middle two elements have been
removed and placed at the beginning of the result. Assume all lists are an even
length

>>> outsideIn2(['C','a','r','t','o','n']) 
['r','t','C','a','o','n'] # rt moves to front
>>> outsideIn2(['H','i']) 
['H','i'] # Hi moves to front so output remains the same.
>>> outsideIn2(['B','a','r','b','a','r','a',' ','A','n','n','e']) 
['r','a','B','a','r','b,','a',' ','A','n','n','e'] # ra moves to front.
'''
length = len(lst)
middle1 = lst.pop((len(lst) / 2) - 1)
middle2 = lst.pop((len(lst) / 2) + 1)

lst.insert([0], middle1)
lst.insert([1], middle2)                  

return lst
```

I'm getting this error:

> middle1 = lst.pop((len(lst) / 2) - 1)
>
> TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note, after you pop `len(lst)/2-1`, everything else shifts up one slot. It makes your math a lot easier if you pop the higher one first. Or, alternatively, if you pop and reinsert one before popping and reinserting the other (because popping `len(lst)/2-1` and inserting `0` leaves the other one in its original place).

Answer (score 5):

When you upgraded to Python 3, the '`/`' operator changed from giving you integer division to real division.  Switch to '`//`' operator.

Comment: One very minor quibble: Python explicitly calls its type `float` rather than `real` to hammer home the fact that it's not _really_ a real number, but a floating-point base-2 rational, and it calls `/` "true division" rather than "real" or "float" division.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `//` operator:

```
middle1 = lst.pop((len(lst) // 2) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explained why you are getting the error.  You need to use `//` instead of `/` (also, just for the record, you need to give `list.insert` integers, not lists).

---

However, I'd like to suggest a different approach that uses [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
def outsideIn2(lst):
    x = len(lst)//2
    return lst[x-1:x+1]+lst[:x-1]+lst[x+1:]
```

This method should be significantly faster than using`list.pop` and `list.insert`.

As proof, I made the below script to compare the two methods with [`timeit.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit):

```
from timeit import timeit

def outsideIn2(lst):

    length = len(lst)
    middle1 = lst.pop((len(lst) // 2) - 1)
    middle2 = lst.pop((len(lst) // 2) + 1)

    lst.insert(0, middle1)
    lst.insert(1, middle2)

    return lst

print(timeit("outsideIn2(['B','a','r','b','a','r','a',' ','A','n','n','e'])", "from __main__ import outsideIn2"))

def outsideIn2(lst):
     x = len(lst)//2
     return lst[x-1:x+1]+lst[:x-1]+lst[x+1:]

print(timeit("outsideIn2(['B','a','r','b','a','r','a',' ','A','n','n','e'])", "from __main__ import outsideIn2"))
```

The results were as follows:

```
6.255111473664949
4.465956427423038
```

As you can see, my proposed method was ~2 seconds faster.  However, you can run more tests if you would like to validate mine.

Comment: You took the words right out of my brain! I thought this would be faster, but timeit proves it, nice!

Comment: @PaulMcGuire - Thank you.  Unfortunately for you however, my method is faster than yours for some reason.  ^_^  You can see for yourself by copying the test script I made and replacing the OP's function with yours.  I bet you you could fix this though by putting the last two lines of yours into one so that you don't make a tuple.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire - Yup, that worked.  Putting those two lines into one makes our solutions neck and neck for speed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pop` and `insert` (especially inserting at positions 0 and 1) can be fairly slow with Python lists.  Since the underlying storage for the list is an array, inserting at position 0 means that the element at position `n-1` has to be moved to position `n`, then the element at `n-2` has to be moved to `n-1` and so on. `pop` has to do the same in reverse. So imagine in your little method how many element moves must be done. Roughly:

```
pop #1 - move n/2 elements
pop #2 - move n/2 elements
insert 0 - move n elements
insert 1 - move n elements
```

So approximately `3n` moves are done in this code.

Breaking the list into 3 slices and reassembling a new list may be more optimal:

```
def outsideIn2(lst):
    midstart = len(lst)//2-1
    left,mid,right = lst[0:midstart], lst[midstart:midstart+2], lst[midstart+2:]
    return mid+left+right
```

Plus you won't run into any weird issues by `pop` changing the length of the list between the first and second call to `pop`. And the slices implicitly guard against index errors when you get a list that is shorter than 2 characters.